# List modifications made to Javascript files from Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, diff, google-chrome-devtools

I routinely modify Javascript files directly from Chrome Developer Tools. I am looking for a way to list all the modifications that I have done on a page.

I know Chrome highlights the tabs where modifications have been done. What I would rather want is a diff between what was originally loaded and the current state.

I can't simply save the files to disk as I have a complex build process generating these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click in the source of any script file and select *"Local modifications..."*. This will allow you to see a history of the changes you've made:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Do you know if there's any way I can copy this diff?!

Comment: @MasterScrat There doesn't seem to be an option for that. But as a workaround you can save the modified file, diff it locally with the original one and get all the changes like that.

Comment: bleaah... not exactly optimal

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developing mode-> Sources -> select your .js file -> Right Click -> Select Local Modification -> Check History Tab